# Ubuntu upgrade from 17.04 to 18.04

Tags: ubuntu, upgrade

I've installed ubuntu 17.04 and I want to upgrade it to 18.04. When I tried to do:

```
 sudo do-release-upgrade
```

I got a message saying `An upgrade from 'zesty' to 'bionic' is not supported with this tool`. Need inputs to proceed on this.

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Your Ubuntu release is not supported anymore.
For upgrade information, please visit:
http://www.ubuntu.com/releaseendoflife

Get:1 Upgrade tool signature [819 B]                                           
Get:2 Upgrade tool [1,257 kB]                                                  
Fetched 1,258 kB in 0s (0 B/s)                                                 
authenticate 'bionic.tar.gz' against 'bionic.tar.gz.gpg' 
extracting 'bionic.tar.gz'

Reading cache

Checking package manager

Can not upgrade 

An upgrade from 'zesty' to 'bionic' is not supported with this tool.
```

Comment: Fill a [bugreport](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs).

Comment: @IporSircer Please stop giving such an ill-advised recommendation. There are specific steps to fix the repositories and put the system up to date. Open source developers are not worthy of such lack of consideration of directing the hordes to them to give them end user support. I would not give end user support masked of bug reports if I were a developer, I have to work and pay my bills too. Have you ever filled an official bug report? I doubt normal end users will not be that happy doing that and doing it right.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro: This is the official way for upgrading: https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/installing-upgrading.html . The developers wrote this. The poster followed the instruction and run into a problem. So this is a bug. Bug of documentation or bug of `do-release-upgrade` command.

Comment: *"For upgrade information, please visit: `http://www.ubuntu.com/releaseendoflife`"* Did you do that? What did you do with the information there?

Comment: This really should be on AskUbuntu.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

This was not properly explained anywhere, here is what you need to do (or how I did it):

Upgrade to 17.04 to 17.10:
[Unable to upgrade from ubuntu 17.04 to 17.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1002439/unable-to-upgrade-from-ubuntu-17-04-to-17-10)

```
sudo cp /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.bak #to be safe
sudo sed -i -re 's/old-releases.ubuntu.com/archive.ubuntu.com/g' /etc/apt/sources.list
sudo sed -i -re 's/zesty/artful/g' /etc/apt/sources.list
sudo apt update
sudo apt dist-upgrade
sudo apt autoremove
```

(Links says to use aptitude instead of apt-get)

Upgrade from 17.10 to 18.04: [EOLUpgrades](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades)

Replace everything in /etc/apt/sources.list with this:

```
## EOL upgrade sources.list
# Required
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ artful main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ artful-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ artful-security main restricted universe multiverse

# Optional
#deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ artful-backports main restricted universe multiverse
```

Then run the upgrade:

```
apt-get update
apt-get dist-upgrade
do-release-upgrade
```

Do what it says when asked and wait for it to finish and you should be done.

### EDIT

According to [WiMantis](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/460306/ubuntu-upgrade-from-17-04-to-18-04/462467#comment1035931_462467), `sudo sed -i -re 's/old-releases.ubuntu.com/archive.ubuntu.com/g' /etc/apt/sources.list` is no longer needed. WiMantis [made a post about it](https://wimantis.ninja/fix-cant-upgrade-ubuntu-17-04//). Relevent part:

```
# Upgrade from 17.04 to 17.10

# backup current sources file (just in case)
sudo cp /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.bak

# change version codename from 'zesty' to 'artful'
sudo sed -i -re 's/zesty/artful/g' /etc/apt/sources.list

# 17.10 has reached it's end of life
# so we fetch from 'old-releases.ubuntu.com'
sudo sed -i -re 's/archive.ubuntu.com/old-releases.ubuntu.com/g' /etc/apt/sources.list

sudo apt update
sudo apt dist-upgrade
sudo apt autoremove
```

```
# Upgrade from 17.10 to 18.04 LTS

# change version codename from 'artful' to 'bionic'
sudo sed -i -re 's/artful/bionic/g' /etc/apt/sources.list

# 18.04 has NOT reached it's end of life yet (due in 2028)
# so we fetch from 'archive.ubuntu.com'
sudo sed -i -re 's/old-releases.ubuntu.com/archive.ubuntu.com/g' /etc/apt/sources.list

sudo apt update
sudo apt dist-upgrade
sudo apt autoremove
```

Comment: Excellent. Yes, I couldn't find a proper explanation either. The docs are really unclear. I think there is some confusion as to whether you're supposed to replace CODENAME in sources.list with your current release code name or the one you're trying to upgrade to. It's really not clear on that point.

Comment: Thanks, this was really helpful. I had a "resolve generated breaks" error when I tried to use `do-release-upgrade`. I solved it using `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` from here, just in case it helps anyone else: https://askubuntu.com/questions/124845/eerror-pkgproblemresolverresolve-generated-breaks-this-may-be-caused-by-hel

Comment: I was very reluctant to run such manual upgrade, but I finally did it (the first part, from zesty to artful) and it went surprisingly well. Unless for one thing : the desktop session went away at some point, so I lost the terminal in which the upgrade was running, during the installation process. For some reason this interrupted, and could be resumed by running apt upgrade again. So I strongly suggest to run this inside screen, or tmux (byobu is great), or local text console (Ctrl Alt F3), or probably ssh session would be more stable than graphical local terminal.

Comment: I still got the same error when following this guide.

Comment: @jonneymendoza Are you on 17.04? Write `lsb_release -a` to get your version.

Comment: The line `sudo sed -i -re 's/old-releases.ubuntu.com/archive.ubuntu.com/g' /etc/apt/sources.list` is not required anymore since artful has been moved to http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/artful/ !

I've gone trough this process yesterday and made a post about it (if someone is interested) : https://wimantis.ninja/fix-cant-upgrade-ubuntu-17-04/

Comment: I don't think 18.04 is due 2028

Comment: sudo sed -i -re 's/([a-z]{2}\.)?archive.ubuntu.com|security.ubuntu.com/old-releases.ubuntu.com/g' /etc/apt/sources.list

Also update the security repos URL, which is required to upgrade in 2022.